# Android Webview focus problem

Tags: android, webview, focus, android-webview

I have an Android webview with a textarea and submit button.

```
<form action="/newmessage" method="post" id="messageform">
  <textarea name="body" id="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="send" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

On tapping in textarea, soft keyboard comes up. On tapping submit button, focus shifts  from textarea to the button and soft keyboard minimizes.

But I want the focus to remain in textarea and soft keyboard up even after submit.
To do that, I changed submit to normal button (and even span) and added an onclick event and did $("#messsage").focus() in that.

Now, focus comes back and soft keyboard comes up too but shows a flickering behavior as focus shifts from textarea to button, back to textarea. (It also messes up scrolling using iScroll, as for a brief while scroll area is more.)

Is there a way to avoid the flickering behavior by *always* keeping focus in textarea and still able to call some javascript on hitting button? Or some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the soft keyboard permanently visible.

Comment: Trying to avoid that as most of the time user will be reading messages. Only when he wants to send a message, I want to show keyboard till the time he hits back/keyboard close.